# TypeScript implicit 'any' type with computed property key

Tags: react.js, typescript, jsx, type-safety

*(irrelevant code removed for demo purposes)*

I am new to using TypeScript and I have this React component which has an object literal inside the component, which I'm then accessing using a computed property key. Everything works as expected but I was getting the following TS error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ keyword: string; hex: string; rgb: string; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ keyword: string; hex: string; rgb: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

I managed to get rid of the error by adding the `: any` to the `formats` object, though I think this is not the best solution?

```js
interface Props {
  keyword: string;
  hex: string;
  rgb: string;
  copyFormat: string;
}

export default ({ keyword, hex, rgb, copyFormat }: Props) => {
  const formats: any = {
    keyword,
    hex: hex.toUpperCase(),
    rgb: `rgb(${rgb})`,
  };

  return <p>{formats[copyFormat]}</p>;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You very rarely need to use `any` in TypeScript because its type-system is so expressive.

The problem is that `copyFormat` is specified to be *any* `string`.

What would happen if you passed `"blahblahblah"` as `copyFormat`? Your types currently allow this!. Then, your code would attempt to do `formats["blahblahblah"]`, but `.blahblahblah` is not a member of  the `formats` object.

You need a more precise type for `copyFormat`. You intended the caller to only pass one of `"keyword"`, `"hex"`, or `"rgb"`. You can make a type that is just those three values like so:

```
interface Props {
  keyword: string;
  hex: string;
  rgb: string;
  copyFormat: "keyword" | "hex" | "rgb";
}
```

It looks like `Props` really holds two things; it holds the actual data, and then a separate argument controlling what you read from it. It might make sense to split it into two arguments:

```
export default ({ keyword, hex, rgb }: Props, copyFormat: "keyword" | "hex" | "rgb") => {
  const formats = {
    keyword,
    hex: hex.toUpperCase(),
    rgb: `rgb(${rgb})`,
  };

  return <p>{formats[copyFormat]}</p>;
}
```

If you don't like typing out all of the possible key options, you could instead use the `keyof` type operator to say that `copyFormat` is any valid key in the `Props` type. TypeScript will see that all of the properties are `string`s and correctly infer the resulting type of `formats[copyFormat]` is thus a `string`.

````
interface Props {
  keyword: string;
  hex: string;
  rgb: string;
}

export default ({ keyword, hex, rgb }: Props, copyFormat: keyof Props) => {
  const formats = {
    keyword,
    hex: hex.toUpperCase(),
    rgb: `rgb(${rgb})`,
  };

  return <p>{formats[copyFormat]}</p>;
};
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the help, Curtis.

I utilized your tips and ended up creating a reusable type interface (which is used in a few places throughout the app): `export interface ColorProps {
  keyword: string;
  hex: string;
  rgb: string;
}`. I then extended that interface and used the `keyof ColorProps` as the type for `copyFormat`: `interface Props extends ColorProps {
  copyFormat: keyof ColorProps;
  onClick: (value: string) => void;
}`. Hope this is a valid way to do things!